# How to refresh or reload the aura component when ever it is calling from list button

Tags: javascript, aura, rerender

Hi we have developed custom import and export functionality, but when i select some file to upload and went back to the opportunity and for the next when ever i am trying to click on the list button to call my component previously selected file is still on the component, it is not opening the fresh instance of the component. I tried with "$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();" in doinit block and in rederer but it is not working.

Can any one suggest how to refresh/reload the aura component every time when called from button.

Below is the Aura component UI : 
[image]

once i upload the file and uploaded the records,
[image]

when i click on back and went to opportunity page and again tried to access the same component it is still showing the above page not the fresh component, i need to force refresh/ reload the URL in order to get the fresh component. How can i over come this issue.

Comment: Are you using URL addressable component?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code

```
setTimeout(function(){ $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: This definitely will not work. Aura events are not fired when outside the Aura life cycle. A minimal change would be to wrap the function in $A.getCallback.

Comment: I tried both, but still it is not working. This my logic for back button :                                                                                     
    ({
    navigateTo : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "/" + cmp.get("v.recordId"),
            "isredirect" : true
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
        $A.getCallback(function(){ $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); }, 3000); 
        //setTimeout(function(){ $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); }, 3000);       
    },

Answer (score 0):

You can try another workaround. This will work for you are requirment.

```
navigateTo : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
   window.setTimeout(function(){ $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); }, 3000); 
   window.location.href = "/" + cmp.get("v.recordId"); }
```